# Stored setInterval returns as undefined in React JS class-based component

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

Good afternoon,

I am attempting to set and clear an interval.  I assign the interval to my state because attempting to declare it anywhere else either isn't allowed (when declared outside of a function) or is limited by scope (when declared inside of a function) or is otherwise inaccessible (when declared outside of the class).  My code is as follows (It's still very much in the testing stage so it's pretty rough.  It is doing what I want it to though, short of clearing the interval):

```
import React, { Component, lazy, Suspense } from 'react';

const Passersby = lazy(() => import('../components/Passersby'));

class Public extends Component {

    state = {
        passersby: null,
        intervalStorer: null
    };

    startJeff = () => {
        this.setState({ passersby: null });
        import('axios').then(axios => {
            axios.get('http://localhost:8080/get_jeff')
        });
        setTimeout(this.stopIt, 10000);
        //remember to call clearTimeout() if defeat conditions are satisfied
        this.checkForJeff();
    }

    checkForJeff = () => {
        if (this.state.passersby === null) {
            this.setState({ passersby: [] });
        }
        this.queryForJeff();
    }

    queryForJeff = () => {
        //setInterval() returns an numerical code, correct?  Why isn't it being stored here?
        const interval = setInterval(this.assignJeff, 1000);
        this.setState({ intervalStorer: interval });
    }

    assignJeff = () => {
        console.log('looked for jeff')
        import('axios').then(axios => {
            axios.get('http://localhost:8080/get_jeff/more_jeffs')
                .then(response => {
                    const folks = response.data;
                    const updatePassersby = this.state.passersby;
                    updatePassersby.push.apply(updatePassersby, folks);
                    this.setState({ passersby: updatePassersby });
                });
        });
    }

    stopIt = () => {
        //this logs in the console as "undefined"
        console.log(this.intervalStorer);
        clearInterval(this.intervalStorer);

        import('axios').then(axios => {
            axios.get('http://localhost:8080/get_jeff/stop_jeff')
        });

    }

    render() {

        let people = null;

        if (this.state.passersby) {
            people = (
                <Passersby
                    name={this.state.passersby.name}
                    activity={this.state.passersby.activity}
                    key={this.state.passersby.id}
                    passersby={this.state.passersby}
                />
            )
        }

        return <div>
            <h1>Jeffs?</h1>
            <button onClick={this.startJeff}>Start the Jeffing</button>
            <button onClick={this.checkForJeff}>More Possible Jeffs?</button>
            <button onClick={this.postInterval}>Interval Test</button>
            <button onClick={this.stopIt}>NO MORE JEFFS</button>
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Jeff Could Be Anywhere...</div>}>
                {people}
            </Suspense>
        </div>

    }
}

export default Public;
```

What do I need to do to get the setInterval() stored properly in my state?

Thanks.

Comment: access `this.state.intervalStorer`

Comment: BTW Good afternoon :)

Comment: N00b status ftw.  That fixed it.  Thanks Siraj!  I will accept your answer in a few days when stack overflow allows me to.

Comment: You can accept it right now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing your state variable incorrectly,

access it as

```
this.state.intervalStorer
```

this.intervalStorer is considered as an uninitialized local variable, that's why it is returning you undefined.